# Is there a way to make get_dummies work faster?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
array = {'id': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3], 'state': ['NY', 'NY', 'CA', 'CA', 'OH', 'AZ', 'NY','AZ']}
df = pd.DataFrame(array)
df.set_index('id', inplace=True)
df2 = pd.get_dummies(df['state'])#.max(level=0)
df2
```

Which gives the following output:

```
    AZ  CA  NY  OH
id              
1   0   0   1   0
1   0   0   1   0
1   0   1   0   0
2   0   1   0   0
2   0   0   0   1
2   1   0   0   0
3   0   0   1   0
3   1   0   0   0
```

I am looking for a fast way to condense it - so there is one row per ID.
Problem is that the result I am getting from df2 from the full dataframe is 2,000,000 rows and 15,000 columns.

I tried both: `.max(level=0)` or `groupby().sum()` - both take days to complete.

Is there a better way?

Comment: Have you tried `pd.crosstab(df.index, df["state"])` ?

Comment: Thanks. but this failed due to memory problems. Do you know how to run it more memory-efficient?

Comment: Are those strings or categoricals?

Comment: They are strings (objects)

Comment: Categoricals take up significantly less memory than strings do and compare faster (generally) as they are essentially int variables with a lookup table. You might consider converting the dtype to category and see if that benefits performance.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Andrej, try the [`pandas.crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) function:

```py
# pd.crosstab(column_a, column_b)

pd.crosstab(df.index, df["state"])
```

For me get dummies was failing due to low memory, however crosstab worked.